# Emulation Station set up

Tags: retropie, emulation

I have run the emulation station setup script and copied over roms for nes, snes, and n64. But when I try to run

```
emulationstation
```

It starts up, but I am greeted with a screen that says

```
We can't find any systems....
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Also for some reason, I do not have a `~/.emulationstation` directory, but the `/etc/emulationstation/es_systems.cfg` file has every system in there

Comment: Make sure you have the correct version, the Pi 1 and the Pi Zero have a different image than the Pi 2 and the Pi 3.

Comment: How can I check what image I have? I installed emulationstation in Raspbian Jessie

Comment: Never-mind I just figured out the issue. I'll post an answer for anyone that runs into this same issue

Answer (score 2):

The issue for me was that I couldn't access the `.emulationstation` folder using `cd ~/.emulationstation` I had to just do `cd .emulationstation`. I then copied the `/etc/emulationstation/es_systems.cfg` file to `.emulationstation` and was able to get in to emulation station.